# Showing that if the PMF of $W$ is symmetric around zero then some parameters entering it are equivalent

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, symmetry

**Summary:** In what follows, I specify the probability mass function (PMF) of a random variable $W$, depending on some parameters $(\lambda,\mu,\lambda',\mu')$. I would like your help to show that 
$$
\text{If the PMF of $W$ is symmetric around zero then $\mu=\mu'$ and $\lambda=\lambda'$}
$$

---

**More details on the structure of the problem:**

Let $P_Y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ be the PMF of $Y$, prescribed by 
$$
\begin{cases}
P(\mu_1)=\lambda_1\\
P(\mu_2)=\lambda_2\\
P(\mu_3)=\lambda_3\\
P(\mu_4)=\lambda_4\\
P(d)=0 & \forall d\neq \mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3,\mu_4
\end{cases}
$$
where $\mu\equiv (\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3,\mu_4)$, $\mu_1<\mu_2<\mu_3<\mu_4$, $\lambda\equiv (\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4)$, $\lambda_1\neq 0$, $\lambda_2\neq 0$, $\lambda_3\neq 0$, $\lambda_4\neq 0$.

---

Let $P_{Y'}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ be the PMF of $Y'$ structured as above but using $\mu'\equiv (\mu_1', \mu_2',\mu_3', \mu_4')$ and $\lambda'\equiv (\lambda_1', \lambda_2',\lambda_3', \lambda_4')$,  potentially different from $\mu, \lambda$. As above, $\mu_1'<\mu_2'<\mu_3'<\mu_4'$, $\lambda_1'\neq 0$, $\lambda_2'\neq 0$, $\lambda_3'\neq 0$, $\lambda_4'\neq 0$.

---

Let $W\equiv Y-Y'$.

---

Assume

1) $\mu_2-\mu_1=\mu_2'-\mu_1'\equiv A$

2) $\mu_4-\mu_3\equiv c>A$

3) $\mu_4'-\mu_3'\equiv f>A$

In what follows I will also use $b\equiv \mu_3-\mu_2$ and $e\equiv \mu_3'-\mu_2'$.

---

**Claim to show**: 
$$
\text{If the PMF of $W$ is symmetric around zero then $\mu=\mu'$ and $\lambda=\lambda'$}
$$

---

---

**My attempts and thoughts:**  I have started to approach this problem by  writing down in a matrix the potential support points of the PMF of $W$ together with some ordering considerations.
$${\tiny
\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1-\mu_1'& < & \mu_1-\mu_1'-A & < & \mu_1-\mu_1'-A -e & < & \mu_1-\mu_1'-A-e-f\\
\wedge & &  \wedge & & \wedge & & \wedge\\
\mu_1+A-\mu_1'& < & \mu_1+A-\mu_1'-A & < & \mu_1+A-\mu_1'-A -e & < & \mu_1+A-\mu_1'-A-e-f\\
\wedge & &  \wedge & & \wedge & & \wedge\\
\mu_1+A+b-\mu_1'& < & \mu_1+A+b-\mu_1'-A & < & \mu_1+A+b-\mu_1'-A -e & < & \mu_1+A+b-\mu_1'-A-e-f\\
\wedge & &  \wedge & & \wedge & & \wedge\\
\mu_1+A+b+c-\mu_1'& < & \mu_1+A+b+c-\mu_1'-A & < & \mu_1+A+b+c-\mu_1'-A -e & < & \mu_1+A+b+c-\mu_1'-A-e-f\\
\end{pmatrix}}
$$

Let $\eta_1,...,\eta_m$ be the support points of $W$ associated with non-zero probabilities $p_1,...,p_m$.

Under the assumptions above, we know that 
$$
\begin{cases}
\eta_1\equiv \mu_1-\mu_1'-A-e-f\\
p_1\equiv \lambda_1\lambda_4'\\
\eta_m\equiv \mu_1+A+b+c-\mu_1'\\
p_m\equiv \lambda_4\lambda_1'\\
\eta_2\equiv \mu_1+A-\mu_1'-A-e-f\\
p_2\equiv \lambda_2\lambda_4'\\
\eta_{m-1}\equiv \mu_1+A+b+c-\mu_1'-A \\
\lambda_{m-1}\equiv \lambda_4\lambda_2' 
\end{cases}
$$
$$ \overbrace{\Downarrow}^{\text{If PMF of $W$ symmetric at $0$}}
$$
$$ \begin{cases}
\mu_1-\mu_1'-A-e-f=-(\mu_1+A+b+c-\mu_1')\\
\lambda_1\lambda_4'=\lambda_4\lambda_1'\\
\mu_1+A-\mu_1'-A-e-f=-(\mu_1+A+b+c-\mu_1'-A )\\
\lambda_2\lambda_4'=\lambda_4\lambda_2' \\
(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4=1, \lambda'_1+\lambda'_2+\lambda'_3+\lambda'_4=1)
\end{cases}
$$

I tried to work on this system but I couldn't show that it implies $\mu=\mu'$ and $\lambda=\lambda'$ (that is, in other words, $\lambda=\lambda'$, $\mu_1=\mu_1'$, $b=e$, $c=f$).

I hence attempted to determine $\eta_3, \eta_{m-2}$ bu that requires to distinguish whether $f>,=,< A+b$ and $c>,=,< A+e$ and the resulting number of cases to analyse is huge.

I'm therefore thinking that the route I took is maybe not efficient and I was wondering whether you could see faster strategies.

Comment: Given your specification of $\mu$, I don't see how it can be symmetric.  Obviously for symmetry $\mu_1 < \mu_2 \leq 0 \leq \mu_3 < \mu_4$, and it must be that $\mu_4 = -\mu_1$ and similarly for $\mu_3$ and $\mu_2$.  This implies that $\mu_4 - \mu_3 = \mu_2 - \mu_1$, which is contradicted by your assumptions.

Comment: Your conditions ensure that $Y$ has a PMF symmetric around zero. Why is that necessary for $W\equiv Y-Y'$ to have a PMF symmetric around zero (which is instead what I'm focused on)?